# React jest-enzyme simulate change throwing warning : Controlled to uncontrolled change

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am working on React 16.8 with jest-enzyme 7.0 and facing a issues in which test case is getting passed but throwing warning :

```
A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled.
```

My input tag is like this :

```
<input type=“text” value={myValue} onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)} />
```

and my test case simulate event was like :

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
wrapper.find(“#myInput”).simulate(“change”, {target: {value: “asdf”}});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasted lots of hours googling and found a fix to this issue by assigning a default value to my input like this :

```
<input type=“text” value={myValue || “”} onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)} />
```

It worked for me..!!